# Jasmine : Expect $http.post() not have been called

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

In an angularjs program I'd like to test with Jasmine if an http post is NOT performed in a test.

I've try the following code :

```
expect($http.post).not().toHaveBeenCalled();
```

But I get "ReferenceError: $http is not defined"

Comment: Show us more code, where are you obtaining `$http` itself? Angular passes services around with DI. Where are you getting your $http?

Comment: Not related but should be 

expect($http.post).not.toHaveBeenCalled()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is error is because you never injected $http into the test. You can do this with the [inject function](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.mock.inject), but for testing `$http` calls, you really should use [$httpBackend](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.$httpBackend)

For requests that you want to make sure they aren't called, you don't need to do anything. Angular throws an error when it gets a request that wasn't expected (as defined by the `expect`  functions on `$httpBackend`). So If a request is made that shouldn't be, the tests will fail from this error thrown from an unexpected request.

Comment: Ok, in other tests I test if $http.post is called with     `scope.httpBackend.expectPOST('MY_ENDPOINT', data)` which works. Now in a test I want to test that a post request is not made. I don't see any  post method in $httpBackend to do kind of test : `expect(scope.httpBackend.post).not.toHaveBeenCalled();` Note that in beforeEach i've inject $httpBackend in my scope : `scope.httpBackend = $httpBackend;`

Comment: This is not entirely true. If you don't call $httpBackend.flush(), you will not get an unexpected request error. If you do call $httpBackend.flush() and the request is not made, you will get a No pending request to flush error. There must be a better way.

Answer (score 7):

This is old but I used the following to test for this.

```
expect($httpBackend.flush).toThrowError('No pending request to flush !');
```